# How to loop code for metaspades assembler through a number of samples?

Tags: bash, loops

I have a number of samples in the following format;

```
CUH001T1_unclassified_unpaired_R1

CUH001T1_unclassified_unpaired_R2

CUH002T2_unclassified_unpaired_R1

CUH002_T2_unclassified_unpaired_R2
```

etc

I am assembling using metaspades and the following code;

```sh
spades.py --meta \
    --pe1-1 CUH001T1_unclassified_paired_R1.fastq \
    --pe1-2 CUH001T1_unclassified_paired_R2.fastq \
    -m 400 -o ../metaspades/CUH001T1
```

I want to be able to loop this through all the samples. I have something like this;

```sh
for i in $(ls *.fastq | sort | uniq); do
    echo "spades.py --meta --pe1-1 "$i".fastq --pe1-2 "$i".fastq -o ../metaspades/"$i" >> metaspades.sh
done
```

The desired output is the sample name for each

I know I need to do something to sort through the unclassified_paired part but I'm very new to bioinformatics and I'm unsure of what to do. Can anyone help?

Comment: There are several problems with `for i in $(ls *.fastq | sort | uniq); do`.  See [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).  Use `for i in *.fastq; do` instead.  (The expansion of `*.fastq` is guaranteed to be sorted and to not contain duplicates.)  Run your shell code through [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find problems like this, and many others.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you are trying to do.  Your example "samples" are strings containing the string `_unpaired_` and with no suffix.  Your example code involves files with names that contain `_paired_`  and have a suffix `.fastq`.

I guess you may have a directory containing multiple pairs of files like

```
XXX_unclassified_paired_R1.fastq
XXX_unclassified_paired_R2.fastq
```

and for each of those pairs you want to run a command like

```
spades.py --meta \
    --pe1-1 XXX_unclassified_paired_R1.fastq \
    --pe1-2 XXX_unclassified_paired_R2.fastq \
    -m 400 -o ../metaspades/XXX
```

If that is what you want, this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean Bash program will print a list of the required commands if it is run in the directory containing the `.fastq` files:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

for pe1_1_file in *_unclassified_paired_R1.fastq; do
    base=${pe1_1_file%_unclassified_paired_R1.fastq}
    pe1_2_file=${base}_unclassified_paired_R2.fastq
    if [[ -e $pe1_2_file ]]; then
        printf 'spades.py --meta --pe1-1 %q --pe1-2 %q -m 400 -o ../metaspades/%q\n' \
            "$pe1_1_file" "$pe1_2_file" "$base"
    else
        printf "WARNING: '%s' does not exist\\n" "$pe1_2_file" >&2
    fi
done
```

- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `base=${pe1_1_file%_unclassified_paired_R1.fastq}`.
- The `%q` specifiers in the `printf` format string are to ensure that the generated commands will work even if the file names contain unusual characters.